# How do i do a production build on AngularCLI rc.1?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-cli, typescript2.0

I just updated to angular-cli 1.0.0-rc1 after following the upgrade instructions on the wiki.

When i run `ng serve` - the app behaves correctly.

When i run `ng build` - the app behaves correctly.

When I run `ng build --target=production --environment=prod`
I get the following:

```
➜  web git:(master) ✗ ng build --target=production --environment=prod
Hash: 1e69750dbc9679bddab0
Time: 69052ms
chunk    {0} main.8839163bd6c77300ac2a.bundle.js (main) 1.11 MB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} styles.014a26b5c21b6bdedf9e.bundle.css (styles) 440 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} scripts.73c5e350c283a9340ddc.bundle.js (scripts) 146 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.f208e8b0304d6a96ac3d.bundle.js (vendor) 2.54 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.1eab99acff53ba884df2.bundle.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in ../api/src/business/dtos/modifier.dto.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at Object.getTokenPosOfNode (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:6768:71)
    at IdentifierObject.TokenOrIdentifierObject.getStart (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80500:23)
    at IdentifierObject.TokenOrIdentifierObject.getText (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80521:77)
    at refactor.findAstNodes.filter (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:139:44)
    at Array.filter (native)
    at refactor.findAstNodes.forEach.node (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:138:14)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _removeDecorators (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:129:10)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:292:33)
 @ ./src/app/model-labels/model-label.component.ts 3:0-51
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ../api/src/business/dtos/document.dto.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at Object.getTokenPosOfNode (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:6768:71)
    at IdentifierObject.TokenOrIdentifierObject.getStart (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80500:23)
    at IdentifierObject.TokenOrIdentifierObject.getText (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80521:77)
    at refactor.findAstNodes.filter (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:139:44)
    at Array.filter (native)
    at refactor.findAstNodes.forEach.node (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:138:14)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _removeDecorators (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:129:10)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:292:33)
 @ ./src/app/document-viewer/document-viewer.component.ts 2:0-51
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ../api/src/business/dtos/models.dto.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at Object.getTokenPosOfNode (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:6768:71)
    at IdentifierObject.TokenOrIdentifierObject.getStart (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80500:23)
    at IdentifierObject.TokenOrIdentifierObject.getText (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80521:77)
    at refactor.findAstNodes.filter (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:139:44)
    at Array.filter (native)
    at refactor.findAstNodes.forEach.node (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:138:14)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _removeDecorators (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:129:10)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:292:33)
 @ ./src/app/model-sublabel/model-sublabel.component.ts 1:0-46
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ../api/src/business/dtos/lens.dto.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at Object.getTokenPosOfNode (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:6768:71)
    at IdentifierObject.TokenOrIdentifierObject.getStart (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80500:23)
    at IdentifierObject.TokenOrIdentifierObject.getText (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80521:77)
    at refactor.findAstNodes.filter (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:139:44)
    at Array.filter (native)
    at refactor.findAstNodes.forEach.node (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:138:14)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _removeDecorators (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:129:10)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/jmurphy/projects/business/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:292:33)
 @ ./src/app/create-lens/create-lens.component.ts 2:0-43
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in main.8839163bd6c77300ac2a.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (FooterComponent) [main.8839163bd6c77300ac2a.bundle.js:7,6]
```

**How do i get my app to compile correctly for production?**

*UPDATE 1:*
Here's an example of one of the offending files. ColumnTypes.TEXT is a public value. As these are just decorators, they have no external dependencies. Again, this works fine for non production builds.

```
import {autoserialize} from "cerialize";
import {ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, JoinColumn, OneToOne, OneToMany, Table, ColumnTypes, CreateDateColumn} from "./export.dtos";

@Table()
export class DTOModifier {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @autoserialize id: number;

  @Column(ColumnTypes.TEXT, {nullable: true})
  @autoserialize label: string;
}
```

Where:

```
static TEXT: ColumnType;
```

Comment: There  must be an issue with document.dto.ts. Try exclude the file from the compile list.

Comment: ng build --prod

Comment: Are there missing the () behind @autoserialize?

Comment: not missing()  - https://github.com/weichx/cerialize

Comment: IT should be static TEXT: ColumnType = "text";

Answer (score 0):

When doing a production build with angluar-cli > beta.27 (i think it was beta 27), you are implicitly using ahead-of-time compilation.

Ahead-of-Time-compilation only works, when the component-members you access from your templates are public. It seems that you have a component with some classmember `text` that is set to private.

The reason for this is, that ngc (the angular compiler) will make a regular typescript-class out of your template, and when trying to compile this file, the temporary template-class has no access to private component-members.

**edit:**

I'm not 100% sure that this is actually your problem, but this is a problem i faced when i started making production builds, and you *could* have the same problem because the errors look similar

Comment: Added source for offending files

Comment: I think it has something to do with _removeDecorators function and the implementation